# Firefox downloads fail randomly after update to 71.0 OSX

Tags: php, firefox, download, filesize

I'm downloading files from my webserver that are stored out of the webroot. PHP is handling the file transfer. Everything works as expected on every other browser, and was working on Firefox until the latest browser update.

Now files will sometimes complete and sometimes fail with the message :

```
xxxxx.part could not be saved, because the source file could not be read.
```

It's completely random, the same file will fail 3 or 4 times then download without a problem, also a file may download at first attempt without issue. It makes absolutely no sense.

I've tried everything listed [HERE](https://ugetfix.com/ask/how-to-fix-source-file-could-not-be-read-error-on-firefox/) and nothing has fixed it.

I've read that it is a problem to do with the server initially reporting a filesize that is smaller than the actual file. Apparently Firefox used to be okay with this but now flags up any files like this as corrupt. It can be disabled in FF prefs but that's not ideal at all as this script is running on a download store serving mp3, wav and zip files.

This is the meat and veg of how I'm serving the files with PHP :

```
if (file_exists($filepath)) {

  if (ini_get('zlib.output_compression')) {
      ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
  }

  set_time_limit(0);
  $fp = @fopen($filepath, 'rb');

  if ($fp) {

      if (strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "MSIE")){
          header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
          header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
          header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. $filename .'"');
          header('Expires: 0');
          header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
          header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
          header('Pragma: public');
          header("Content-Length: ". self::get_file_size($filepath));
      } else {
          header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
          header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
          header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. $filename .'"');
          header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
          header('Expires: 0');
          header('Pragma: no-cache');
          header("Content-Length: ". self::get_file_size($filepath));
      }

      fpassthru($fp);
      fclose($fp);

      ob_flush();
      flush();
  }
}
```

And this is the function that calculates the filesize (it's located in the same class):

```
public static function get_file_size ($file) 
{
    $fp = @fopen($file, "r");
    @fseek($fp,0,SEEK_END);
    $filesize = @ftell($fp);
    fclose($fp);
    return $filesize;
}
```

As I say, this works perfectly on all other browsers and was working on FF until this latest update.

Anybody got any potential server side solutions to ensure accurate filesize data is being transmitted?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that this is because you're checking the file size by opening it with mode `r` instead of mode `rb`. Change it to the latter. (Also, if you don't have a good reason to not use [`filesize`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php), then just do that instead of writing your own.)

Comment: Nope that didn't fix anything. Tried changing to 'rb' and also moved it into the same function as I realized I was opening and closing the file twice wasting resources (funny how you can see things more clearly when you post it as a question). Also tried jogging that on completely and simply using `filesize($filepath)` instead but still getting the same problem.

Comment: Ahh your solution did work, just not the way I was trying to use it. I was declaring the filesize in a variable `$filesize = filesize($filepath);` and then using it in the header `header("Content-Length: ". $filesize);` - That didn't work... But when I switched it to `header("Content-Length: ". filesize($filepath));` it now appears to be working fine. Thanks so much bro, you saved me a massive headache!

Comment: Nope scrap that.. Still happening :( Must be a firefox bug, that's not good times...

Comment: It's almost certainly not a Firefox bug.

Comment: A bit of further reading and it maybe nginx compressing the file, resulting in the smaller filesize. Just trying to find out how to disable compression for a non-webroot dir now.

Comment: No, not that either. Just disabled gzip on the entire server and it's still happening. Again, all of the time downloads are working perfectly in all other browsers (Chrome, Brave & Safari). So weird.

Comment: Been at this for hours now, still no joy. Could it be because I'm renaming the files in the header which is causing the filesize to increase? If so how would I compensate for that?

Answer (score 1):

Wow this is embarrassing :/

After hours and hours of trying everything I could think of it turns out that all I needed to do was exit the script at the end of it. Strange how none of the other browsers have a problem with this but Firefox is obviously a bit more picky.

```
exit;
```

Comment: Do you have a `?>` at the end of your file that you didn't show us?

Comment: This is a small part of a big list of functions being passed from class to class so yes, more than likely.

Comment: That's the real reason. You don't need a `?>` at the end of PHP scripts, and if you have one anyway, then anything after it (including trailing newlines) will end up in the output.